# How server can validate client certificate in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I know server certificate can be verified by client using.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.CreateHttp( url );
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += ValidateServerCertificate;
```

but if I need to validate the client certificate on server that it is issued by a proper CA, it is not expired and the certificate is not revoked, then how I will verify as two way SSL requires both client and server certificates to be verified.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a service certificate node in the server configuration file to configure client certificate information. Then customize a class that inherits X509CertificateValidator on the server side, and override the verification method in this class to verify the client's certificate. For specific operations, you can refer to:[X.509 Certificate Validator.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/x-509-certificate-validator)

Comment: I want to check whether the certificate is issued by a proper Root CA, it is not expired and the certificate is not revoked.

Comment: How can I check all these with X.509 Certificate Validator.